# PowerShell to Robocopy exclude is not working

Tags: powershell, robocopy

In PowerShell I am trying to copy files from one location to another and want some files to be excluded. so I am using the following commands:

```
$Excludefiles="`"$((get-content 'C:\WorkingDirectory\List.txt') -join'""')`""

robocopy "C:\aa\" "C:bb\" /XF $Excludefiles
```

It seems it is excluding everything.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Take a close look at the content of your variable `$Excludefiles`. I could imagine it is not what you expect it to be.  ;-)

Comment: What you think the syntax would be. I did not get any syntax error though.

Comment: With `-join'""'` you connect the elements of an array with the charachters you specify. So you have a double `"` between your elements. And no `"` at the first position and no `"` at  the last position. Is it that what you wanted?

Comment: Excludes are passed as a space-separated list, so I would first try with a simple `... /xf (Get-Content 'list.txt')`. If that doesn't suffice and you need to add double quotes around the individual excludes do it like this: `$Excludefiles = (Get-Content 'list.txt') -replace '^|$', '"'`.

Comment: HI Olaf, as per your instruction I changed the syntax to $Excludefiles="`"$((get-content 'C:\WorkingDirectory\List.txt') -join'" " " "')  `""  now it is still skipping everything. However It is listing Exc file : all the file names that I want to skip.

Comment: I tried the below syntax too,  it is skipping all the files ,$Excludefiles=(get-content 'C:\List.txt') -replace '^|$', '"'

robocopy "C:\aa" "C:\bb" /XF $Excludefiles

Comment: Does robocopy exclude file , when I am trying to use it for only one file even it is not working.   robocopy "C:\aa" "C:\bb" /XF "C:\WorkingDirectory\xxx.xml" , it skpped all the files.

Comment: The command worked just fine when I tested it. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] with sample folder content, your script, the content of the exclude file for your sample folder, `robocopy` output, and the content of the destination folder after the command ran.